# Xcode 12 not displaying all search results

Tags: xcode, xcode12

When I search for something in the Project navigator, some results are missing from the list. If I delete my query and write it again, it starts to work again - but only in come cases.

What is this issue and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This issue has been fixed in Xcode 12.0.1.

---

**Original answer:**

This is a bug in Xcode 12 caused by typing too fast. (Yeah, I know...)

Essentially, what happens is that Xcode starts fetching the list, but if you type the second character *before* the first query finishes (or the third before the second finishes, you get the idea), you'll get a list with missing items. What likely happens is that Xcode tries to filter the previous list to save time instead of querying all files, and in this case, it filters the incomplete list instead of waiting for the query to finish.

There are 2 easy ways to get around this issue for now:

1. Use the **Open Quickly** menu instead (<kbd>⌘⇧O</kbd>, Cmd+Shift+O)
2. Type slower. (no joke, this is what I usually do)

Hopefully this will get fixed soon.

Comment: @matt One year later...